# Cannot use PerformanceObserver in Cypress

Tags: typescript, performance, testing, cypress, playwright

Is the a way to use the PerformanceObserver in Cypress?
For me, it does not seem to fire.

I have done it in playwright

```js
const { chromium } = require('playwright')

(async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('website')

  const totalBlockingTime = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      let totalBlockingTime = 0
      new PerformanceObserver(function (list) {
        const perfEntries = list.getEntries()
        for (const perfEntry of perfEntries) {
          totalBlockingTime += perfEntry.duration - 50
        }
        resolve(totalBlockingTime)
      }).observe({ type: 'longtask', buffered: true })

      // Resolve promise if there haven't been long tasks
      setTimeout(() => resolve(totalBlockingTime), 5000)
    })
  })

  console.log(parseFloat(totalBlockingTime)) // 0

  await browser.close()
})()
```

Here is what I tried but it does not seem to fire

```js
let totalBlockingTime = 1;
cy.window().then((win) => {
  const o = new win.PerformanceObserver((list) => {
    const entries = list.getEntries();
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.entryType === "longtask") {
        totalBlockingTime += entry.duration;
      }
    });
  });
  o.observe({
    entryTypes: ["longtask"],
    buffered: true,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the code you have is basically correct, but the timing of adding the observer is critical with Cypress.

Ideally, you want to add it just after the test runner has set up the window and is about to load the page, so `onBeforeLoad` event.

I don't know much about `longtask`, except it's marked experimental, but here is a proof-of-concept test that uses the `mark` and `measure`

```js
cy.visit("http://example.com", {
  onBeforeLoad: (win) => {
    const o = new win.PerformanceObserver((list) => {
      list.getEntries().forEach(entry => {
        console.log("Name: "       + entry.name      +
                    ", Type: "     + entry.entryType +
                    ", Start: "    + entry.startTime +
                    ", Duration: " + entry.duration  + "\n");
      })
    });
    o.observe({
      entryTypes: ['measure', 'mark', 'longtask'],
      // buffered: true,                           // see note
    });
    win.performance.mark('registered-observer')    // issue mark
  },
})
  
cy.wait(1000)                 // vary this wait to see performance duration change

cy.window().then(win => {
  console.log('measuring...')
  win.performance.measure('after waiting');
})
```

**Note**

The `buffer:true` entry throws a warning

> The PerformanceObserver does not support buffered flag with the entryTypes argument.

[image]

**Console log**

```js
Name: registered-observer, Type: mark, Start: 48.900000005960464, Duration: 0

measuring...
Name: after waiting, Type: measure, Start: 0, Duration: 1093.199999988079

Name: same-origin-ancestor, Type: longtask, Start: 1103.800000011921, Duration: 98
```